# Rule for all targets in make - even if the file exists

Tags: makefile

I want to create a `Makefile` that outputs `foo` no matter what target name is given to `make`.

So all of these should work:

```
$ make
foo
$ make a
foo
$ make foobar
foo
```

The following `Makefile` does almost what I want:

```
all %:
    @echo foo

.PHONY: all
```

However it fails if there exists a file with the same name as the target:

```
$ touch abc
$ make abc
make: `abc' is up to date.
```

As `.PHONY` doesn't accept pattern rules, I don't know how I can get `make` to ignore every file.

Comment: FWIW the syntax `all % :` is not valid in newer versions of GNU make; you must be using an old version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
all $(MAKECMDGOALS): ; @echo foo
.PHONY: all $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```